# Port Forwarding to Server not Working, but Remote Management Does

Tags: web-hosting, server

As I said in my other (deleted) question, I am now running the Abyss Web Server because of its simplicity. However, almost everything works until I found out I can't connect to it when I type in my external IP address. Although it is dynamic and changes every 10 minutes, I always used the latest one. I decided to turn on my router's "Remote Management", which is changing the router's configuration from the Internet, to test if it's my ISP blocking me, and it turns out not! I typed in my external IP address (port 80) for the Remote Management and it worked! The port forwarding, which I set is the following does not work:

- TCP/UDP (actually I tried just TCP and just UDP, but to no avail)
- Beginning Port: 80
- Ending Port: 80
- Server IP: 10.0.0.4 (yes, I checked it twice)

Does anyone know why my router isn't working the way it's supposed to be?